# How do you keep Properties Dialog open while Closing the App that opened it?

Tags: shell, winapi, com

I am working on something that pulls up a context menu.   I want to be able to close the app while leaving open things like "properties".  What happens is if you open the context menu, select "properties", it opens the properties dialog and closes the context menu just fine.  But when I close my app, the properties window also closes.

The question is: How do you keep that window open?  If you can't, how could the app tell if it has a window/dialog dependent on it open?  EnumWindows doesn't show it; Spy++ shows the Properties Dialog stands on its own as well (under desktop).

```
CComPtr<IContextMenu> pMenu;
CComPtr<IShellFolder> pFolder;
PCUITEMID_CHILD pidl = NULL;
SHBindToParent(item.pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&pFolder, &pidl);
pFolder->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 1, &pidl, IID_IContextMenu, NULL, (void**)&pMenu);
UINT flags = CMF_NORMAL | CMF_CANRENAME;
pMenu->QueryContextMenu(menu, CID_FIRST, CID_LAST, 0x7fff, flags);
.
.
.
// command invocation
CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
info.fMask = CMIC_MASK_NOASYNC | CMIC_MASK_PTINVOKE; // I've played around with flags
info.hwnd = toolbar.m_hWnd; // I've played around with this value
info.lpVerb = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(cid - CID_LAST);
info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
info.ptInvoke = point;
pMenu->InvokeCommand((CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO*)&info);
```

TIA!!

Comment: The shell properties dialog runs in-process so will close when the process exits. It might work to use `ShellExecuteEx()` with the verb set to `L"properties"`.

Answer (score 0):

**EnumWindows doesn't show it**

If I misunderstood something, please tell me.

This is my test:

[image]

[image]

The second screenshot is what I got with `EnumWindows`, in my opinion, For some APP Properties Dialog , you can get it with `EnumWindows`.

At the same time, as @Jonathan Potter said that, the shell properties dialog runs in-process, it is true that you can open the properties dialog independently with `ShellExecuteEx`.

Only as a supplement, if you just want to open the properties dialog independently, you can use the api above.This way, when you close the app, you can reopen the properties dialog if you are not bothered.

Minimal code example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj_core.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Shell32.lib")

class ProcessReference : public IUnknown {
public:
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
    {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        *ppv = NULL; return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
    }
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        LONG lRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
        if (lRef == 0) PostThreadMessage(m_dwThread, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
        return lRef;
    }
    ProcessReference()
        : m_cRef(1), m_dwThread(GetCurrentThreadId())
    {
        SHSetInstanceExplorer(this);
    }
    ~ProcessReference()
    {
        SHSetInstanceExplorer(NULL);
        Release();
        MSG msg;
        while (m_cRef && GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
private:
    LONG m_cRef;
    DWORD m_dwThread;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct CoInit { HRESULT m_hr; CoInit() { m_hr = CoInitialize(0); } ~CoInit() { if (SUCCEEDED(m_hr)) CoUninitialize(); } } coinit;
    ProcessReference ref;
    IShellItem*pSI;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemInKnownFolder(FOLDERID_Windows, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, L"Explorer.exe", IID_IShellItem, (void**)&pSI);
    if (hr) return hr;
    IContextMenu*pCM;
    hr = pSI->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFUIObject, IID_IContextMenu, (void**)&pCM);
    pSI->Release();
    if (hr) return hr;

    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { 0 };

    info.cbSize = sizeof info;
    info.lpFile = "C:\\Users\\strives\\Desktop\\print.txt";
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
    info.lpVerb = "properties";

    ShellExecuteEx(&info);


}
```

**Updated:**

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { 0 };

info.cbSize = sizeof info;
info.lpFile = "C:\\Users\\strives\\Desktop\\Test.txt";
info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
info.lpVerb = "openas";

ShellExecuteEx(&info);
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: That Sleep is a ugly hack and there is a correct solution for this.

Comment: `EnumWindows` wasn't finding it as a dependent (child) of the app window.   Not sure why the Sleep is there, but Anders seems to say it's needed but another way to do whatever is needed.  Would help if that was indicated.   Thanks to all!  I'll do some testing in a bit.

Comment: You also need `SHSetInstanceExplorer()` or it still closes properties.   That was what Andres must have been referencing.   The "keep your process alive until that COM object is released" link which is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080528-00/?p=22163

Comment: I'll also point out that for the context menu, while it works for Properties, `ShellExecuteEx` doesn't work for other items, say selecting "edit with notepad++", instead it just opens the file in the associated application.   However the `InvokeCommand()` method does work.  It just doesn't support the `SHSetInstanceExplorer`.   Is there one that supports everything or am I going to have to _stricmp() a bunch of verbs?

Comment: @user3161924 Thank you for your reminder, I have corrected it. In addition, as far as I know, using `ShellExecuteEx` can only achieve the "open with" step.

Answer (score 0):

The properties dialog is in-process.

You need to call [`SHSetInstanceExplorer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shsetinstanceexplorer) and [keep your process alive until that COM object is released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080528-00/?p=22163):

```
int main()
{
    struct CoInit { HRESULT m_hr; CoInit() { m_hr = CoInitialize(0); } ~CoInit() { if (SUCCEEDED(m_hr)) CoUninitialize(); } } coinit;
    ProcessReference ref;
    IShellItem*pSI;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemInKnownFolder(FOLDERID_Windows, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, L"Explorer.exe", IID_IShellItem, (void**) &pSI);
    if (hr) return hr;
    IContextMenu*pCM;
    hr = pSI->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFUIObject, IID_IContextMenu, (void**) &pCM);
    pSI->Release();
    if (hr) return hr;
    //HMENU menu = CreatePopupMenu();
    //pCM->QueryContextMenu(menu, 0, 1, 0x7fff, CMF_NORMAL);
    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    info.fMask = CMIC_MASK_NOASYNC; // I've played around with flags
    info.hwnd = NULL; // I've played around with this value
    info.lpVerb = "Properties";
    info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    //info.ptInvoke = point;
    hr = pCM->InvokeCommand((CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO*)&info);
    pCM->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Testing, I found that using `->InvokeCommand()` with the SHSetInstanceExplorer still terminates (the reference count is 1 on destruction - using class from second link).   But using  `ShellExecuteEx()` it does work (count is 2 on destruction, closing properties then allows termination).  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you calling SHSetInstanceExplorer at the start of your program? 1 means the object is still alive, you have to wait for it to become 0 like in the example I linked to.

Comment: Yes, I mean it's 1 before releasing my reference.   `ShellExecuteEx()` works, it's 2 before releasing so it does work, just not with `->InvokeCommand`.   Using same helper class indicated in that link.

Comment: You should not release anything, the ProcessReference class does that for you when it goes out of scope.

Comment: That's the one I'm referring to.  I put a break point and check the value.

Comment: Well, if you're saying what you have works, then I presume it does, the question is why wouldn't using the IShellFolder with SHBindToParent of a pidl, then GetUIObjectOf() from the IShellFolder work where as your IShellItem does?  Also difference in using value instead of string for the verb.

Comment: Can't you just take my code and modify it until it fails? Yes, IShellItem is basically just IShellFolder+pidl. Make sure you have initialized COM correctly!

Comment: I don't see any real difference from what I'm doing other than IShellFolder instead of IShellItem.  I'm using OleInitialize.  As mentioned, ShellExecuteEx method works, using the InvokeCommand doesn't ???